# error in aspectj Project as change the Compilation Level

Tags: java, eclipse, aspect, ajdt

I install eclipse_4.3, JDK_1.8.0, and I use ajdt_2.2.3 library for Aspect. 
until I don't change Compiler Compliance level, the default is 1.4, my project is OK.
but when I write this code in my Project:

```
List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
```

so I have to change Compiler Compliance level to 1.5, but when I do this, I get this error in first line of Aspect:

> "The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

Comment: Did you try to refresh, clean and rebuild? Close the project and reopen it?

Comment: @A4L : yes, i do these works several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution,

i don't know why sometimes this error appears in my aspect, but i just try to install jre7 and use this library instead jre8 in my project build path, and all things OK.